# Set open mp threads for use 80% CPU

Tags: c++, multithreading, openmp, cpu-usage

I am working on c++ loop and would like set threads for it use 80~85% of CPU. Example of loop:

```
#pragma omp parallel
    {
#pragma omp  for schedule (dynamic) 
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000000000; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 10000000000; j++) {
                int toto = i + j;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I want it work for all CPU, have you any suggestion?

Comment: OpenMP has no method of setting thread priority that I know of. It's platform-specific. What platform are you running?

Comment: i'm using windows platform

Comment: Okay, then I think maybe you need to use Windows system calls. Look up GetThreadPriority and SetThreadPrority.

Comment: This is not possible on Windows. The standard logic holds: "what if two applications would do this?". Also, it's underspecified. Do you want to intentionally slow down by 15-20%, or do you want to take away the CPU from other programs? I.e. do you want to go up from 50% CPU use or down from 100%?

Comment: I want to take away the CPU from other programs but at the same time i want the best performance for my loop. Because when my loop use 100% of CPU, It's frooze my comptuer and i can't use other application during that.

Answer (score 0):

Since you said you're on Windows, you need to get the thread handle, then use

```
int GetThreadPriority(HANDLE hThread);
```

system call, which returns a thread priority running, I think, from -15 to 15. Then call

```
BOOL SetThreadPriority(HANDLE hThread, int nPriority);
```

to set the new priority.

Higher priority numbers mean more CPU time is dedicated to that thread.

I haven't heard of an ability to set thread priority through OpenMP.

Comment: If you have an OpenMP implementation which supports OMP_PLACES=sockets (several don't in their Windows port), and your platform has enough "sockets," you could restrict the number of sockets an application runs on, leaving one or more free for another application.  Unless you have multiple sockets, it's unlikely that multiple applications could share resources effectively, even if the total cache footprint is small enough.  I believe there's more overhead for pinning on Windows than on other OS.  In the example you pose, OpenMP might be useless, optimization might well eliminate the loop.